# Running 1st and 2nd level retry forever not calling IErrorHandler

Tags: rebus, rebus-azureservicebus

The code below enables 2nd level retry and IErrorHandler.

The problem is that IErrorHandler is **never** invoked.

```
    var activator = new BuiltinHandlerActivator();

   activator.Register((bus, mc) => new Handler(mc, bus));
        Configure.With(activator)
           .Transport(t => t.UseAzureServiceBus(Consts.ServiceBusConnectionString, Consts.Subscriber1))
           .Options(o =>
                    {

              o.SimpleRetryStrategy(maxDeliveryAttempts: 2,
                                              secondLevelRetriesEnabled: true,
                                              errorQueueAddress: "poison");

             o.Decorate<IErrorHandler>(c => new MyErrorHandler(c.Get<IErrorHandler>()));


                    }).Start();
```

**Handler**

```
class Handler : IHandleMessages<string>,
          IHandleMessages<IFailed<object>>
    {
        readonly IBus _bus;
        readonly IMessageContext _messageContext;
        public Handler(IMessageContext messageContext, IBus bus)
        {
            _messageContext = messageContext;
            _bus = bus;
        }

        public async Task Handle(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Handle(string message): {0}", message);
            throw new Exception("Handle(string message)");
        }

        public async Task Handle(IFailed<Object> message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Handle(IFailed<Object> message): {0}", message);
            await _bus.Advanced.TransportMessage.Defer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

        }

    }
```

Specifically, below is the sequence of running 1st and 2nd level retry:

Calling sequences based on maxDeliveryAttempts is 2:

1 calling Handle(string message), 
   throw exception within Handle(string message)

2 calling Handle(string message)
   throw exception within Handle(string message)

3 calling Handle(IFailed message)

4 calling Handle(IFailed message)

5 calling Handle(string message), 
   throw exception within Handle(string message)

6 calling Handle(IFailed message)

**Repeat 5 and 6 forever**

**Question A:**

Why is IErrorHandler not invoked?

How to invoke IErrorHandler after calling Handle(IFailed message) 2 times based on maxDeliveryAttempts of 2.

That is:

Calling sequences based on maxDeliveryAttempts is 2:

1 calling Handle(string message), 
   throw exception within Handle(string message)

2 calling Handle(string message)
   throw exception within Handle(string message)

3 calling Handle(IFailed message)

4 calling Handle(IFailed message)

**5 calling IErrorHandler**

**6 Move to next message**

**Update**

The same issue occurs on `IHandleMessages<IFailed<string>>`.

**Update 2**

Error below:

```
 Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
 Error      Unable to locate repository containing directory
 'C:\ReBus\Rebus-master\Rebus'. Rebus   C:\Users\username\.nuget\packages\microsoft.build.tasks.git\1.0.0-beta-63127-02\build\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Git.targets 20
```

Clicking the error above shows this in VS

```
<Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Git.LocateRepository Directory="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)" >
  <Output TaskParameter="Id" PropertyName="_GitRepositoryRoot" />
</Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Git.LocateRepository>
```

**Update 3**
Result below of running this https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/blob/master/Rebus.Tests/Bugs/VerifyThisParticularThingAboutSecondLevelRetries.cs

```
[INF] Rebus.Threading.TaskParallelLibrary.TplAsyncTask (Worker#3): Starting periodic task "CleanupTrackedErrors" with interval 00:00:10
[INF] Rebus.Threading.TaskParallelLibrary.TplAsyncTask (Worker#3): Starting periodic task "DueMessagesSender" with interval 00:00:01
[INF] Rebus.Bus.RebusBus (Worker#3): Bus "Rebus 1" setting number of workers to 1
[DBG] Rebus.Bus.RebusBus (Worker#3): Adding worker "Rebus 1 worker 1"
[INF] Rebus.Bus.RebusBus (Worker#3): Bus "Rebus 1" started
[DBG] Rebus.Workers.ThreadPoolBased.ThreadPoolWorker (Rebus 1 worker 1): Starting (threadpool-based) worker "Rebus 1 worker 1"
[DBG] Rebus.Pipeline.Send.SendOutgoingMessageStep (Worker#3): Sending "HEJ MED DIG" -> "whatever"
Handle(string message): HEJ MED DIG
[WRN] Rebus.Retry.ErrorTracking.InMemErrorTracker (Rebus 1 worker 1): Unhandled exception 1 while handling message with ID "667c8cfd-5ce5-46a6-9394-32d1386ef7de"
System.Exception: Handle(string message)
   at Rebus.Tests.Bugs.VerifyThisParticularThingAboutSecondLevelRetries.Handler.<Handle>d__4.MoveNext() in C:\ReBus\Rebus.Tests\Bugs\VerifyThisParticularThingAboutSecondLevelRetries.cs:line 81
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Rebus.Pipeline.Receive.HandlerInvoker`1.<Invoke>d__14.MoveNext() in C:\ReBus\Rebus\Pipeline\Receive\HandlerInvoker.cs:line 154
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Rebus.Pipeline.Receive.DispatchIncomingMessageStep.<Process>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\ReBus\Rebus\Pipeline\Receive\DispatchIncomingMessageStep.cs:line 66
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Rebus.Sagas.LoadSagaDataStep.<Process>d__6.MoveNext() in C:\ReBus\Rebus\Sagas\LoadSagaDataStep.cs:line 66
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Rebus.Pipeline.Receive.ActivateHandlersStep.<Process>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\ReBus\Rebus\Pipeline\Receive\ActivateHandlersStep.cs:line 47
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Rebus.Pipeline.Receive.HandleRoutingSlipsStep.<Process>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\ReBus\Rebus\Pipeline\Receive\HandleRoutingSlipsStep.cs:line 40
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Rebus.Retry.Simple.FailedMessageWrapperStep.<Process>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\ReBus\Rebus\Retry\Simple\FailedMessageWrapperStep.cs:line 42
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Rebus.Pipeline.Receive.DeserializeIncomingMessageStep.<Process>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\ReBus\Rebus\Pipeline\Receive\DeserializeIncomingMessageStep.cs:line 34
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Rebus.DataBus.ClaimCheck.HydrateIncomingMessageStep.<Process>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\ReBus\Rebus\DataBus\ClaimCheck\HydrateIncomingMessageStep.cs:line 51
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Rebus.Pipeline.Receive.HandleDeferredMessagesStep.<Process>d__12.MoveNext() in C:\ReBus\Rebus\Pipeline\Receive\HandleDeferredMessagesStep.cs:line 121
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Rebus.Retry.FailFast.FailFastStep.<Process>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\ReBus\Rebus\Retry\FailFast\FailFastStep.cs:line 51
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Rebus.Retry.Simple.SimpleRetryStrategyStep.<DispatchWithTrackerIdentifier>d__10.MoveNext() in C:\ReBus\Rebus\Retry\Simple\SimpleRetryStrategyStep.cs:line 118
Handle(string message): HEJ MED DIG
[WRN] Rebus.Retry.ErrorTracking.InMemErrorTracker (Rebus 1 worker 1): Unhandled exception 2 while handling message with ID "667c8cfd-5ce5-46a6-9394-32d1386ef7de"
System.Exception: Handle(string message)
   at Rebus.Tests.Bugs.VerifyThisParticularThingAboutSecondLevelRetries.Handler.<Handle>d__4.MoveNext() in C:\ReBus\Rebus.Tests\Bugs\VerifyThisParticularThingAboutSecondLevelRetries.cs:line 81
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Rebus.Pipeline.Receive.HandlerInvoker`1.<Invoke>d__14.MoveNext() in C:\ReBus\Rebus\Pipeline\Receive\HandlerInvoker.cs:line 154
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Rebus.Pipeline.Receive.DispatchIncomingMessageStep.<Process>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\ReBus\Rebus\Pipeline\Receive\DispatchIncomingMessageStep.cs:line 66
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Rebus.Sagas.LoadSagaDataStep.<Process>d__6.MoveNext() in C:\ReBus\Rebus\Sagas\LoadSagaDataStep.cs:line 66
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Rebus.Pipeline.Receive.ActivateHandlersStep.<Process>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\ReBus\Rebus\Pipeline\Receive\ActivateHandlersStep.cs:line 47
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Rebus.Pipeline.Receive.HandleRoutingSlipsStep.<Process>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\ReBus\Rebus\Pipeline\Receive\HandleRoutingSlipsStep.cs:line 40
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Rebus.Retry.Simple.FailedMessageWrapperStep.<Process>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\ReBus\Rebus\Retry\Simple\FailedMessageWrapperStep.cs:line 42
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Rebus.Pipeline.Receive.DeserializeIncomingMessageStep.<Process>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\ReBus\Rebus\Pipeline\Receive\DeserializeIncomingMessageStep.cs:line 34
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Rebus.DataBus.ClaimCheck.HydrateIncomingMessageStep.<Process>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\ReBus\Rebus\DataBus\ClaimCheck\HydrateIncomingMessageStep.cs:line 51
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Rebus.Pipeline.Receive.HandleDeferredMessagesStep.<Process>d__12.MoveNext() in C:\ReBus\Rebus\Pipeline\Receive\HandleDeferredMessagesStep.cs:line 121
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Rebus.Retry.FailFast.FailFastStep.<Process>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\ReBus\Rebus\Retry\FailFast\FailFastStep.cs:line 51
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Rebus.Retry.Simple.SimpleRetryStrategyStep.<DispatchWithTrackerIdentifier>d__10.MoveNext() in C:\ReBus\Rebus\Retry\Simple\SimpleRetryStrategyStep.cs:line 118
Handle(IFailed<Object> message): FAILED: HEJ MED DIG
[DBG] Rebus.Pipeline.Receive.DispatchIncomingMessageStep (Rebus 1 worker 1): Dispatching "System.String, mscorlib" "667c8cfd-5ce5-46a6-9394-32d1386ef7de" to 1 handlers took 4 ms
Disposing Rebus.Activation.BuiltinHandlerActivator
[DBG] Rebus.Pipeline.Receive.HandleDeferredMessagesStep (Rebus 1 worker 1): Deferring message "String/667c8cfd-5ce5-46a6-9394-32d1386ef7de" until 2019-06-04T10:36:51.6554132+01:00
[INF] Rebus.Bus.RebusBus (Worker#3): Bus "Rebus 1" setting number of workers to 0
[DBG] Rebus.Workers.ThreadPoolBased.ThreadPoolWorker (Rebus 1 worker 1): Worker "Rebus 1 worker 1" stopped
[DBG] Rebus.Bus.RebusBus (Worker#3): Removing worker "Rebus 1 worker 1"
[INF] Rebus.Threading.TaskParallelLibrary.TplAsyncTask (Worker#3): Stopping periodic task "DueMessagesSender"
[INF] Rebus.Threading.TaskParallelLibrary.TplAsyncTask (Worker#3): Stopping periodic task "CleanupTrackedErrors"
[INF] Rebus.Bus.RebusBus (Worker#3): Bus "Rebus 1" stopped
Disposing System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
```

Answer (score 0):

What do the logs say?

To help you get on your way, I just created this little test case with a verification that it does on fact work as expected: [VerifyThisParticularThingAboutSecondLevelRetries.cs](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/blob/master/Rebus.Tests/Bugs/VerifyThisParticularThingAboutSecondLevelRetries.cs)

If you run the test, it should log a bunch of stuff (namely a couple of stack traces from the delivery attempts), and then the message should be dispatched as an `Failed<string>`, which is compatible with the handler for `IFailed<object>`.

Comment: I tested it manually, I cannot build Rebus project to run the test at the moment. I also tested it for IHandleMessages<IFailed<string>> type, which has the same issue.

Comment: Should I create a ticket on Rebus github to track this issue?

Comment: So before the issue is fixed, what is the best method to avoid the issue? Disable 2nd level retry?

Comment: when you say "(...) I cannot build Rebus project to run the test at the moment (...)", what do you mean then?

Comment: Visual studio cannot compile. The Target Framework on Rebus project is blank on my station. To run the test, which branch should be downloaded https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus? which version to build the app, I tried to build it, but get the error `C:\ReBus\Rebus-master\scripts>build.cmd rebus
Please invoke the build script with a version as its second argument.` Is this the quickest way to build?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using? The target frameworks are .NET 4.5, .NET 4.6, and .NET Standard 2.0, so you need the appropriate targeting packs installed too. And sure, you can also build it with the build script by typing e.g. `scripts\build rebus 5.3.1` – but that won't help you run the tests, you probably need Visual Studio to do that.

Comment: I have VS 2017 and .NET core 2.2, and .NET 4.7. However, I manually tested this issue, and confirm that it exists for both object and string types.

Comment: Ok... your Visual Studio sounds fine... and the target framework combobox is blank, when a project has multiple targets... so, again: What do you mean when you say "(...) Visual studio cannot compile.(...)"? It must give you some kind of error...

Comment: I ran `dotnet restore`, and re-compile it, but still get errors. Please see update 2 on OP.

Comment: My guess is that you just downloaded the source code? It seems the build needs it in Git repository form.... could you do a proper `git clone`?

Comment: I get it working now. and the test failed due to timeout, which means the same issue exist. Do you want me to post the test result here?

Comment: That's weird – the test passes on my machine and on the buildserver. Yes please, if you can reproduce the issue with a failing test, then I'll be happy to debug it for you.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The test passed because it has no assertion and will always pass. It throws exception. Please see update 3.